# Clear Countdown Timer when screen in back in focus

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In a journey of learning React Hooks (to transition from Class components), I am building a simple countdown timer on a React Native app. I am noticing that the timers are not correctly cleared whenever the screen is focused.

These are my two effect hooks:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener("focus", () => {
      // do something
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setInterval(() => {
      let timer = timerState;
      if (timer <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timerId);
      } else {
        timer = timer.subtract(1, "s");
        const minutes = timer.minutes();
        const seconds = timer.seconds();
        setTimerMins(minutes);
        setTimerSecs(seconds);
        setTimerState(timer);
      }
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      return () => window.clearInterval(timerId);
    };
  }, [navigation, minsLeftNextCheckIn]);
```

The first `useEffect()` is to capture screen focus. The second one is to update the timer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue yesterday... Any reference to that `timerId` gets lost once useEffect completes.

I solved it by declaring `let timerId` **outside** the component entirely. Then you can assign it and clear it from wherever, and you will only ever have one. Just check it exists each time before you clear it, e.g. `timerId && window.clearInterval(timerId);`